# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Request.Form["ElementName"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.form

I want to access the value of an HTML input element in C#. 
The HTML Code is:

```
<input id="tbASPHTMLAdd" type="text" />
```

I need to push the value of this input box to an ASP Listbox, the code is here:

```
protected void bAddASPHTML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbItems.Items.Add(Request.Form["tbASPHTMLAdd"].ToString());
}
```

But every time I came to the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

When I remove the `.ToString()` it pushes me something in my listbox, but with no value

No, I do not want to add the `runat="server"` attribute. It is to demonstrate a few things.

Greets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mention name attribute of textbox, ID is used for client purpose only, when you submit page all input element submit information with its name attribute as a key.

```
<input id="tbASPHTMLAdd" type="text" name="tbASPHTMLAdd" />
```

Comment: Do I have to do the same thing with an HTML button? I've given it a name attribute and try to read it in the page_load.
`if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //some other stuff
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["bAddHTMLHTML"].ToString()))
                {
                    lStatus.Text = "HTML Button was clicked.";
                }
            }` Is this the right way?

Comment: I figured it out. I need a button with the attribute `type="submit"`